# Android let one media player stop the other

Tags: android, media

I develop an app and because it doesn't sound good, if two sounds overlay, i want to make a sound stop when the next one is playing. I tried it like that

Button1:

```
 MediaPlayer mediaPlayerW = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.w1);      
              if(mediaPlayerW.isPlaying()){
                 mediaPlayerW.stop();}
                else{
                 mediaPlayerW.start();
                } }
```

Button2:

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayerW = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.w2);       
              if(mediaPlayerW.isPlaying()){
                 mediaPlayerW.stop();}
                else{
                 mediaPlayerW.start();
                } }
```

The problem now is, that the mPlayer always gets a new ID and therefore that doesn't stop the "old" sound.

Then I tried it with setDataSource but I still had to create new objects of MediaPlayer, so the IDs still changed.

Anyone an idea about that?

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is not *scalable* and will not efficiently fit your needs.

Android designed a solution to address the issue you are currently facing : The [`AudioFocus`](http://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/audio-focus.html) APIs.

This solution is much more scalable, as it will work with a virtually infinite number of `MediaPlayer` objects and will have the benefit of working across all your applications.